# conditional regex for selecting strings from end anchor

Tags: regex

regex

```
(?<=\/)(?(?=[0-9]{4,5}$)(something 1-1)|(something 1-2))
```

expected result

```
/12345 -> 45
/123456 -> 456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern first asserts `/` to the left from the *current position*, and then uses an if clause at the *current position* asserting 4-5 digits till the end of the string.

If you want to get the last 2 digits when the if clause is true, you would still have to get to the end of the string by matching what comes before you can capture.

You might use 2 capture groups:

```
(?<=\/)(?(?=[0-9]{4,5}$)\d{2,3}(\d\d)|\d{3}(\d+))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\/)` Assert `/` directly to the left
- `(?` If clause

  - `(?=[0-9]{4,5}$)` Assert 4-5 digits till the end of the string
  - `\d{2,3}(\d\d)` Match 2-3 digits and capture 2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{3}(\d+)` Match 3 digits and capture the rest of 1+ digits
- `)` Close the if clause

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gtVOaa/1)

---

Instead of using an if clause and a lookbehind, you can also use an alternation:

```
\/(?:\d{2,3}(\d\d)|\d{3}(\d{3}))$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i4MCkP/1)